# Extracting value from page's response

Tags: http, testing, html-table, loadrunner

I'm trying to run a simple script in LoadRunner but I'm having some problems trying to save values into parameters. 
I'd like to save the content of a table into various parameters but I think I'm doing something wrong... 
The HTTP response is the following 
[image]

What I'd like to do is save "12538680", "R87051901" etc. into parameters to be able to reuse the script in every situation...

Comment: "LB=<td align=\"center\" class=\"listRowBold\" valign=\"middle"\>"
"RB=</td>"
"ORD=ALL"

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter arrays as follows,

```
web_reg_save_param_ex("ParamName=ELEMENT","LB=<td align=\"center\" class=\"listRowBold\" valign=\"middle"\>","RB=</td>","Ordinal=All", LAST );
```

The first match is saved as ELEMENT_1, the second match is saved as ELEMENT_2, and so forth. You can retrieve the total number of matches by using the following term: ParamName_count. For example, to retrieve the total number of matches saved to the parameter array, use:

TotalNumberOfMatches=atoi(lr_eval_string("{ELEMENT_count}"));

Comment: it doesn't work. It always says: "The "ELEMENT" argument (number 1) is unrecognized or misplaced"

Comment: The "ELEMENT" argument (number 1) is unrecognized or misplaced"  - means there is a mistake in the first arugument used "ELEMENT", you have to use "ParamName=ELEMENT".

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. In case it didn't work, save a backup, then try to regenerate the script with "non HTML-generated elements in separate steps and use concurrent groups".

```
web_reg_save_param_ex(
        "ParamName=Elements",
        "LB=<td align=\"center\" class=\"listRowBold\" valign=\"middle\">",
        "RB=</td>",
        "Ordinal=1",
        SEARCH_FILTERS,
        "Scope=ALL",
        LAST);
```